# R - Calculate the sum of time difference

Tags: r, datetime

I want to sum up the times of two rows and then find the min, max, mean, etc. But I failed at the first hurdle, because I don't even know where to start.

The data looks like this:

```
23/07/2022, 18:59, ObjectA
23/07/2022, 11:16, ObjectA
23/07/2022, 10:10, ObjectB
23/07/2022, 11:11, ObjectB
```

What I want is to get the total amount of time between each daily entry, and also to distinguish between the two objects.

Comment: First, I'd suggest converting from text to a datetime object, e.g. `df$dt = lubridate::dmy_hm(paste(df$dates, df$times))` Then you can perform math on it.

Comment: That worked and I've now got a datetime column, but I still need to know how to do the datediff() for each object. I'm assuming this is going to be some kind of FOR loop.

Comment: I'd suggest `library(dplyr); df %>% arrange(dt) %>% group_by(object) %>% mutate(time_diff = dt - lag(dt)) %>% summarize(min = min(time_diff, na.rm = TRUE), max = max(time_diff, na.rm = TRUE), mean = mean(time_diff, na.rm = TRUE))`.  btw, for R questions, it's often helpful to include data in the form of code since  various data structures and data types can print identically. Often easiest to run `dput(head(YOUR_DATA_OBJECT))` and paste the output into your question.